# How insert structure elements in structure tree using code of lua

Tags: luatex

In one of the questions i asked,how insert spans around paragraphs,formulas etc. Now i need insert not only spans,but structure elements in structure tree at least for paragraphs at first,but in perspective,for formulas,tables,heads etc,such as do it tagpdf package. Now i can only redefine commands for start and end of document and insert \tagstructbegin{tag=Document}\tagstructend but i can't do it for each paragraph,formula,list,item of list ETC. As i understood,the best way for automatical tagging of documents it use callbacks in lua and work with node tree,but how i can get and modify structure tree,at least for paragraphs and formulas,using lua language. I know,that context,probably,support automatical tagging of pdf,but i want works with lualatex. Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: Sorry but imho your question is much to vage and broad for this site.  And imho you will have to patch/redefine commands like \list and \item too, only with lua it won't work (context doesn't do this only with lua either).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Ok,but even you wrote in your examples,that for list,which have several levels it not so easy do it. Also i don't know,how to do automatical tagging of tables. Ulrike,if its not so difficult for you,add please functions in tagpdf.lua for adding some structure elements. For example i mean,that if i get in callback,for example,paragraph or formula,i surround it by spans and apply your function for this node and now this paragraph not only surround by spans,but information about it will insert in structure tree.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I tryed study code of your package,especially file tagpdf.lua,but as i understoode,in this moment you only save information about structures in tables,but not modify structure tree in lua code,so you do it only via latex,but i want have functions,which do it via lua. Because it will be very useful for me,when i modify paragraph and formula. Or help me please,how i can modify structure tree from lua code myself. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I have no idea why you want to modify the structure in lua. You will have to give concrete code that demonstrates with *one* simple case what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Ok,i will try explayn to you my idea. Our main purpose is to do automatical tagging of all parts of documents. Some things,such as catching start of paragraph,formula etc we can do using lua code. So i can insert mc elements,but i need in function,which allow to insert structure elements,because without it we can't do fully tagged pdf.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer So,i hope,you understood,why i need in function,which programmatically insert structure elements in structure tree. This function,in my opinion,must be in your module tagpdf.lua and it must have the same arguments,as in command \tagstructbegin,including arguments for associating files. So if you consider,that you dont need add this functions for tagpdf.lua,suggest please ways for me,how i can do,for example,automatic tagging of paragraphs and formulas.

Comment: @Ulrike FischerI start hard study latex and lualatex only at start of this year and you,in my opinion,expert in latex and in lualatex,so your opinion in this question is very necessary and important for me. May be i couldn't achieve automatic tagging of pdf document using features of lua callbacks or simple latex/lualatex features,and i need in some scripts,for example on python,which insert commands of your package or in modifying of source code of latex/lualatex? Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm quite willing to help and to add whatever could be useful. But you must show code! I can't help you if you only give more or less vage descriptions and don't make public whatever you have coded already. Show what you have, e.g. put it somewhere on github and show an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I sent message with example on your email.